# Create a Facebook Page for my Facebook App

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-page

I have a Facebook App, and I want to create a Facebook Page for it. But nowhere can I find an option to do that.

Where am I supposed to be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on "app details" in the developers section of your app and under Contact info you should see "Create a New Facebook Page" button.

Comment: I created a page but the page does not show my app. I also expect the app to show the link the page I created for, but it does not. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link

> https://developers.facebook.com/apps/< YOUR_APP_ID >/settings/advanced/

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdECJ.png)